# How to escape “*” character inside script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

We have a powershell script that requires escaping the `*` character.

PS C:\test> .\jre\bin\java.exe -cp .\test.jar com.test.a123 h256 *

I want to escape above star....

Unable to get any clue in google, any idea on this please?

Answer (score -2):

The generic [PowerShell escape character](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html) is a grave (`), although I must admit, I can't think of a use case where you would need to escape an asterisk. Remember you can always use string literals too:

```
@'
  String literal here
'@
```